# Brand new coder in need of assistance

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am very new to this and could use some help. Don´t even think I posted the code correctly :/ Do anyone know how I can use the search bar to show accordions with mathing name, and hiding the ones that dont match. Would love some feedback :D I get it to work pretty good on my end, but it won´t search correctly and it bothers me a great deal!  Thanks!

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 130px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6%;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<br><br>
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Søk..">

<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion Example</h2>

  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Test 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Test 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Test 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you forget to post your javascript? How are you trying to use your search function without it actually having a function? Also your stylesheet reference and scripts should be in a   tag

Assuming you want to use javascript to eliminate options that aren't part of your search request, this is the function you should use to do it (it will run when you press enter while in your text input):

```
$("#myInput").on("keydown", function myFunction(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

            var parent = document.getElementById('accordion');

            for (i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
                var title = parent.children[i].children[0].children[0].children[0].textContent.toLowerCase();

                if (title.includes(text) === true) {
                    parent.children[i].setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
                } else {
                    parent.children[i].setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

So your end code should look something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        input[type=text] {
  width: 130px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6%;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 25%;
}
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Søk..">

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Accordion Example</h2>

        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Test 1</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Test 2</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Test 3</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $("#myInput").on("keydown", function myFunction(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

                var parent = document.getElementById('accordion');

                for (i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
                    var title = parent.children[i].children[0].children[0].children[0].textContent.toLowerCase();

                    if (title.includes(text) === true) {
                        parent.children[i].setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
                    } else {
                        parent.children[i].setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

EDIT:

For every search text input you have, create a function like the first one demonstrated but replace {--YOUR ID--} with the id of that text input.
Replace the script at the bottom with this:

```
$("#{--YOUR ID--}").on("keydown", function myFunction(e) {
  function search();
});

function search() {
var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        var parent = document.getElementById('accordion');

        for (i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
            var title = parent.children[i].children[0].children[0].children[0].textContent.toLowerCase();

            if (title.includes(text) === true) {
                parent.children[i].setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
            } else {
                parent.children[i].setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This is so cool! Can´t even imagine how you did this. I started coding for fun about 4 weeks ago, with no prior background. REally fun, but hard to learn. One thing though. IS it possible to achieve this without hitting enter? That would be the ultimate dream. I tried using a filter list code, like this:

Comment: <script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>

Comment: Another problem with this is that i can´t use your code if I have several sections of accordions. I have like 6 different sections with a <h1> text between all of them. When I search in the search bar only the results from the first accordion hides. :/

Comment: Have a look at the Edit: bit at the bottom ^^

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! :)